# The command 'react-native run-android' shows up errors although there is an emulator running (or device connected)

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I started a react-native project with 'react-native init' and was created without errors, however, when I used the command 'react-native run-android' in the project directory this is what I got:

```
        throw er
        ^

Error: EIO: i/o error, read
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:675:18)
    at Object.readSync (D:\myProjects\react-native\ReactTodoApp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:138:28)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:540:20)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:575:19)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:645:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18).
```

The same error appears although that android emulator is running or an android device connected, all the same.

I need to know what is the solution to this.
I am using react-native 0.50.3, react-native-cli 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a Node related error.
Try restarting Node server. Node cannot read polyfills.js. This can happen if multiple command instances are running in same directory at same time.

- Sometimes cleaning cache works
- Updating or reinstalling react native is a suggested fix.
  You could uninstall react-native and then use the following command:
  `npm install react@reactversion --save`.
  Note (reactversion) is your desired version you want to have.
  You could also just try reinstalling it as: 
  `npm install react --save`
  Or upgrade with:
   `npm update react-native`